# php submit button and form radio

Tags: php, mysql, forms, radio-button

I'm trying to do script which is sends information to SQL, but I have problem with submit button and form radio, can anyone help me with it?

This IF doesn't work properly

```
if (isset($_POST['test'])) {
if(isset( $_POST['odp']))
```

This is all code of PHP
http://wklej.org/id/1003412/

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work properly"? Is it adding nothing? The wrong thing? The right information, to the wrong place?

Comment: i'm guessing you want to be using an `empty($_POST['test'])` check instead of isset

Comment: Don't use `isset`, use `empty`.

Comment: The problem is that inquiry dosen't work well, it can't show table with SQL, you can see result on http://skuterpl.vot.pl/egzamin/test/test.php

Comment: I think you should also provide the HTML of the form so that we can see what is being submitted to the PHP code you linked there.

Answer (score 0):

For one, after viewing your code it seems that you would do best to combine the two if's, as below:

```
if ((isset($_POST['test']) && isset( $_POST['odp']))
{
    code to execute;
}
```

What are the values you are getting for isset( $_POST['test']) and isset( $_POST['odp'])?  You may want to try echoing them out to see if they are the actual values you are expecting.  You also can try echoing something right after the two if(isset's, as it may be part of the executed code that is not working, and not the actual if statements.

empty($_POST['test']) may work better as well, same as poster above stated.

Comment: An IF within another IF is the same as &&

Comment: But your answer does not help or address his issue!

Comment: The bottom part of my answer does, maybe I should've reversed the order and answered first, giving my suggestion last.

Comment: I changed to if (isset($_POST['test']) && isset($_POST['odp'])) but it dosen't help

Answer (score 0):

For the header, in the code you provided you currently have that line commented out.  Another tip is that a header redirect must be done before anything is outputted, you currently have it after a print line and a few echo lines.  To fix this, you can move it to a function above all of the other code, and then call that function when needed.

Edit: This was meant to answer the last question posted on this page.